# Get missed calls in windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

For Windows Mobile 6, I'd like to get the count of missed calls in my application.

Is there a function to retrieve the missed calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [SystemState.PhoneMissedCalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.phonemissedcalls.aspx) property.